# Stop script from looping on CSV column header?

Tags: imacros

This code creates a new CSV on my desktop. It pulls links from a source CSV. The source CSV is a column of URL links. In the output new CSV, it creates a column 
titled Column_1_Name (as I want it to on row 1), then on the next row it places the extracted text from the URL scrape. The problem is, on the next line in the CSV (row 3) it repeats the column header again (Column_1_Name), then the next extracted data. Then Column_1_Name header again (row 5), then extracted data. Etc.

**I need to know how to just have the Column_1_Name header placed once into the new CSV, and then have the code continue on through the data extraction loop until it has finished the number required URLs from the source CSV.**

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR

'Setting the column header in our output CSV File
URL GOTO=www.google.com
ADD !EXTRACT <SP>Column_1_Name<SP>
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/Users/preston/Desktop/ FILE=New_File_Name{{!NOW:mm-dd-yy}}


SET !DATASOURCE /Users/preston/Desktop/SourceCSV_File.csv
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
'Start at line 2 in the file (below)
SET !LOOP 2
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 


'Extracting Data into our New_File_Name.csv from our SourceCSV_File.csv, the source file contains a column header, and rows of URL links
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:random-class-name EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/Users/preston/Desktop/ FILE=New_File_Name{{!NOW:mm-dd-yy}}
```

Comment: Hey @php12345, I have just run into a brick wall with imacros. I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532248/imacros-submitting-textarea-form-enter-key-maybe if you happen to know the answer you'd be my savior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following workaround can be helpful to you:

```
'Start at line 2 in the file (below)
SET !LOOP 2
SET firstFolder "/Users/preston/Desktop/"

'Setting the column header in our output CSV File
URL GOTO=www.google.com
SET !EXTRACT <SP>Column_1_Name<SP>
SET firstFolder EVAL("({{!LOOP}} == 2) ? '{{firstFolder}}' : '';")
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER={{firstFolder}} FILE=New_File_Name{{!NOW:mm-dd-yy}}
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !EXTRACT NULL

SET !DATASOURCE /Users/preston/Desktop/SourceCSV_File.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}} 

'Extracting Data into our New_File_Name.csv from our SourceCSV_File.csv, the source file contains a column header, and rows of URL links
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:random-class-name EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=/Users/preston/Desktop/ FILE=New_File_Name{{!NOW:mm-dd-yy}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your code and still had the same issue. If you would like to test yourself, you can change out the ATTR=CLASS:random-class-name to ATTR=CLASS:os-seller-name and the script will run once you have the source file titled correctly in the code along with your output file location on your own computer. Here is the source CSV: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k-0_Ys-ZrgoV2OXPntTXakBwUQgi5EWhA1FrTczj4wM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output I got - https://gyazo.com/81d51f5ce752265ce6890f7e4d40e2c0

Comment: You're right. I updated the code. Just add the line: `SET !EXTRACT NULL` .

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. Is there a simple way to set the column header part of the code to conditionally play on Loop 1 only? This would solve the issue of the code starting over to the beginning after every "random-class-name" extraction. Would like to understand if that's possible, because right now it goes to Google.com then to the source file URL, then google.com, then source file URL, etc.

Comment: You can find a similar solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312093/how-to-set-a-loop-in-imacros).